# Adding custom permissions to imported models

Tags: python, django, permissions, models, authentication

In my Django project, I would like to add a custom permission to the User model imported from `django.contrib.auth`.

(Specifically, a permission to allow/deny the user to change their password).

I do understand how to [add permissions to my own model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#custom-permissions), however, I would like the ability to extend an *existing* model.

Is this possible?

Comment: you can try to monkey patch the user model in the runtime, but it's one ugly hack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These [instructions](http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/) are a bit outdated, but should give you an idea on how to extend the `User` model via inheritance, so that you could add any new functionality to the subclass.